# jcarousel plugin doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I tried to use [jcarousel](https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel) on my page
I didn't get any error in console but it just doesn't work.

I added libraries and code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.jcarousel-autoscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.jcarousel-control.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.jcarousel-1').jcarousel({
            vertical: true,
            'wrap': 'both',
            'list': '.jcarousel-list',
            'scroll', '+=2'
        })
        .jcarouselAutoscroll({
        });

        $('.jcarousel-prev').jcarouselControl({
            target: '-=1'
        });

        $('.jcarousel-next').jcarouselControl({
            target: '+=1'
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/mDmZ5/2/

I need to show only two items and use arrows to leaf through.
Can someone explain me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration object for jCarousel is an invalid object declaration (you have a comma between `scroll` and it's value instead of a colon). Try this instead:

```
$('.jcarousel-1').jcarousel({
    vertical: true,
    'wrap': 'both',
    'list': '.jcarousel-list',
    'scroll': '+=2'
})
```

Note: Your jsFiddle won't work because you can't link source from Github.

Comment: and in your fiddle there was a semi-colon at the end of the same line (`'scroll': ...`). Don't see it in your question, but may be the same problem. Please look in your console for any other errors